# ServiceStack HyperMedia

Tags: rest, servicestack, hypermedia

Is there a preferred method/example to implement hypermedia links with service stack. Should I just try to follow the concepts laid out in this article or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance
Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this earlier answer for one way of [adding hypermedia links to ServiceStack responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351944/hypermedia-links-with-servicestack-new-api).

The [Reverse Routing section](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#reverse-routing) on the documentation on [Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) should also be helpful in generating urls from DTO's.