# Support for Link headers in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I am planning to generate Link Headers for the sake of pagination of my REST API results.

For reference, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/9707-link-header.html describes how we should use link headers to describe our results in pages.

Are there C# classes or approaches in ServiceStack that I can resuse rather than writing my own classes and making sure that the Link headers are RFC compliant.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#page-6

It would be desirable if I could simply build a LinkHeader object, populate with relevant data and have the framework take care of formatting it correctly and inserting the header.

Is there any such thing? What have others done?

Comment: Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18351944/hypermedia-links-with-servicestack-new-api what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Alexey. This link is very helpful. Its very close to what I was looking for.